# How can I use *.d.ts files in my Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library, npm-package

I am currently in the process of developing an Angular package and encountering some issues related to proto files. I've attempted to convert my proto files into .d.ts files to use in my library service. However, when trying to use these .d.ts files within my service, I'm receiving various errors.
My most recent attempt to address the problem involved defining the declarations within the .d.ts file as a module. This allowed me to successfully build the library. However, a new issue arose; the .d.ts files are not being included in the build process, which results in users being unable to use them after installation.

I will provide all the errors, file types, and additional relevant details in the form of code snippets and screenshots.
[Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDN6R.png)

[An error I get while importing the module (but it doesn't prevent build for some reason)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDQnT.png)

That's my hello-module.d.ts file

```
import * as $protobuf from "protobufjs";
import Long from 'long';
/** Represents a HelloWorldService */
 declare module 'hello-module'
{
export class HelloWorldService extends $protobuf.rpc.Service {

    /**
     * Constructs a new HelloWorldService service.
     * @param rpcImpl RPC implementation
     * @param [requestDelimited=false] Whether requests are length-delimited
     * @param [responseDelimited=false] Whether responses are length-delimited
     */
    constructor(rpcImpl: $protobuf.RPCImpl, requestDelimited?: boolean, responseDelimited?: boolean);

    /**
     * Creates new HelloWorldService service using the specified rpc implementation.
     * @param rpcImpl RPC implementation
     * @param [requestDelimited=false] Whether requests are length-delimited
     * @param [responseDelimited=false] Whether responses are length-delimited
     * @returns RPC service. Useful where requests and/or responses are streamed.
     */
    public static create(rpcImpl: $protobuf.RPCImpl, requestDelimited?: boolean, responseDelimited?: boolean): HelloWorldService;

    /**
     * Calls hello.
     * @param request HelloRequest message or plain object
     * @param callback Node-style callback called with the error, if any, and HelloResponse
     */
    public hello(request: IHelloRequest, callback: HelloWorldService.helloCallback): void;

    /**
     * Calls hello.
     * @param request HelloRequest message or plain object
     * @returns Promise
     */
    public hello(request: IHelloRequest): Promise<HelloResponse>;
}

export namespace HelloWorldService {

    /**
     * Callback as used by {@link HelloWorldService#hello}.
     * @param error Error, if any
     * @param [response] HelloResponse
     */
    type helloCallback = (error: (Error|null), response?: HelloResponse) => void;
}

/** Properties of a HelloRequest. */
export interface IHelloRequest {

    /** HelloRequest text */
    text?: (string|null);
}

/** Represents a HelloRequest. */
export class HelloRequest implements IHelloRequest {

    /**
     * Constructs a new HelloRequest.
     * @param [properties] Properties to set
     */
    constructor(properties?: IHelloRequest);

    /** HelloRequest text. */
    public text: string;

    /**
     * Creates a new HelloRequest instance using the specified properties.
     * @param [properties] Properties to set
     * @returns HelloRequest instance
     */
    public static create(properties?: IHelloRequest): HelloRequest;

    /**
     * Encodes the specified HelloRequest message. Does not implicitly {@link HelloRequest.verify|verify} messages.
     * @param message HelloRequest message or plain object to encode
     * @param [writer] Writer to encode to
     * @returns Writer
     */
    public static encode(message: IHelloRequest, writer?: $protobuf.Writer): $protobuf.Writer;

    /**
     * Encodes the specified HelloRequest message, length delimited. Does not implicitly {@link HelloRequest.verify|verify} messages.
     * @param message HelloRequest message or plain object to encode
     * @param [writer] Writer to encode to
     * @returns Writer
     */
    public static encodeDelimited(message: IHelloRequest, writer?: $protobuf.Writer): $protobuf.Writer;

    /**
     * Decodes a HelloRequest message from the specified reader or buffer.
     * @param reader Reader or buffer to decode from
     * @param [length] Message length if known beforehand
     * @returns HelloRequest
     * @throws {Error} If the payload is not a reader or valid buffer
     * @throws {$protobuf.util.ProtocolError} If required fields are missing
     */
    public static decode(reader: ($protobuf.Reader|Uint8Array), length?: number): HelloRequest;

    /**
     * Decodes a HelloRequest message from the specified reader or buffer, length delimited.
     * @param reader Reader or buffer to decode from
     * @returns HelloRequest
     * @throws {Error} If the payload is not a reader or valid buffer
     * @throws {$protobuf.util.ProtocolError} If required fields are missing
     */
    public static decodeDelimited(reader: ($protobuf.Reader|Uint8Array)): HelloRequest;

    /**
     * Verifies a HelloRequest message.
     * @param message Plain object to verify
     * @returns `null` if valid, otherwise the reason why it is not
     */
    public static verify(message: { [k: string]: any }): (string|null);

    /**
     * Creates a HelloRequest message from a plain object. Also converts values to their respective internal types.
     * @param object Plain object
     * @returns HelloRequest
     */
    public static fromObject(object: { [k: string]: any }): HelloRequest;

    /**
     * Creates a plain object from a HelloRequest message. Also converts values to other types if specified.
     * @param message HelloRequest
     * @param [options] Conversion options
     * @returns Plain object
     */
    public static toObject(message: HelloRequest, options?: $protobuf.IConversionOptions): { [k: string]: any };

    /**
     * Converts this HelloRequest to JSON.
     * @returns JSON object
     */
    public toJSON(): { [k: string]: any };

    /**
     * Gets the default type url for HelloRequest
     * @param [typeUrlPrefix] your custom typeUrlPrefix(default "type.googleapis.com")
     * @returns The default type url
     */
    public static getTypeUrl(typeUrlPrefix?: string): string;
}

/** Properties of a HelloResponse. */
export interface IHelloResponse {

    /** HelloResponse text */
    text?: (string|null);
}

/** Represents a HelloResponse. */
export default class HelloResponse implements IHelloResponse {

    /**
     * Constructs a new HelloResponse.
     * @param [properties] Properties to set
     */
    constructor(properties?: IHelloResponse);

    /** HelloResponse text. */
    public text: string;

    /**
     * Creates a new HelloResponse instance using the specified properties.
     * @param [properties] Properties to set
     * @returns HelloResponse instance
     */
    public static create(properties?: IHelloResponse): HelloResponse;

    /**
     * Encodes the specified HelloResponse message. Does not implicitly {@link HelloResponse.verify|verify} messages.
     * @param message HelloResponse message or plain object to encode
     * @param [writer] Writer to encode to
     * @returns Writer
     */
    public static encode(message: IHelloResponse, writer?: $protobuf.Writer): $protobuf.Writer;

    /**
     * Encodes the specified HelloResponse message, length delimited. Does not implicitly {@link HelloResponse.verify|verify} messages.
     * @param message HelloResponse message or plain object to encode
     * @param [writer] Writer to encode to
     * @returns Writer
     */
    public static encodeDelimited(message: IHelloResponse, writer?: $protobuf.Writer): $protobuf.Writer;

    /**
     * Decodes a HelloResponse message from the specified reader or buffer.
     * @param reader Reader or buffer to decode from
     * @param [length] Message length if known beforehand
     * @returns HelloResponse
     * @throws {Error} If the payload is not a reader or valid buffer
     * @throws {$protobuf.util.ProtocolError} If required fields are missing
     */
    public static decode(reader: ($protobuf.Reader|Uint8Array), length?: number): HelloResponse;

    /**
     * Decodes a HelloResponse message from the specified reader or buffer, length delimited.
     * @param reader Reader or buffer to decode from
     * @returns HelloResponse
     * @throws {Error} If the payload is not a reader or valid buffer
     * @throws {$protobuf.util.ProtocolError} If required fields are missing
     */
    public static decodeDelimited(reader: ($protobuf.Reader|Uint8Array)): HelloResponse;

    /**
     * Verifies a HelloResponse message.
     * @param message Plain object to verify
     * @returns `null` if valid, otherwise the reason why it is not
     */
    public static verify(message: { [k: string]: any }): (string|null);

    /**
     * Creates a HelloResponse message from a plain object. Also converts values to their respective internal types.
     * @param object Plain object
     * @returns HelloResponse
     */
    public static fromObject(object: { [k: string]: any }): HelloResponse;

    /**
     * Creates a plain object from a HelloResponse message. Also converts values to other types if specified.
     * @param message HelloResponse
     * @param [options] Conversion options
     * @returns Plain object
     */
    public static toObject(message: HelloResponse, options?: $protobuf.IConversionOptions): { [k: string]: any };

    /**
     * Converts this HelloResponse to JSON.
     * @returns JSON object
     */
    public toJSON(): { [k: string]: any };

    /**
     * Gets the default type url for HelloResponse
     * @param [typeUrlPrefix] your custom typeUrlPrefix(default "type.googleapis.com")
     * @returns The default type url
     */
    public static getTypeUrl(typeUrlPrefix?: string): string;
}
}
```

And that is my service. The file path of the term hello-module is specified in package.json

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import *  as Hello from 'hello-module';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProtoLibService {

  constructor(private value:Hello.HelloRequest) {
   }
  bastir()
  {
    this.value.text="Berkay";
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

[The error I get when I want to use my library in another project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FErTn.png)

I tried to use it by giving definitions like include type but it didn't work, I tried to import it directly as berkay.d.ts but it didn't work; Actually, I've tried many things, I'm open to any ideas and I'm waiting for your ideas.